# How to create default menu inside route Ember.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ember.js

I have made jsbin code for my Ember js application here http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qicizidu/2/edit?html,css,js,output

So i want when i click on Item A, and then on A i want that ABCD menu on the left to stay there, not dissappear. Thanks

Comment: If possible can you create a simplified jsbin to illustrate your problem?  It's difficult to know exactly what you're trying to do just based on your description and if you have a jsbin people can often modify it to do exactly what you want which makes it easier for you.  You can use this template to get started: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qicizidu/1/edit

Comment: I have edited the post, so you can see jsbin code now. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code needs to be modified as follows,

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/vazorici/1/edit

**js**

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource("v" , {path : "/v"},function(){
    this.route("a" , {path : "/a"});
  });
  this.route("u" , {path : "/u"});


});
```

**hbs**

```
 <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="v"> 


        <div class="col-md-4" >
          <h2">Title</span></h2>
          <ul>
            <li>{{#link-to 'v.a'}}A{{/link-to}}</li>
            <li>B</li>
            <li>C</li>
            <li>D</li>

        </ul>


         <div class="col-md-8">
        {{outlet}}
      </div>

      </div>

</script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="v/a"> 

<p>Submenu content</p>

</script>
```